# Does recreating an RLS policy in a transaction expose data?

Tags: sql, postgresql, kubernetes, row-level-security

Say I have an RLS policy on a table, and I realize I goofed and forgot a command in the policy, so can't `ALTER` it; it must be `DROP`/`CREATE`ed. I'm using rolling updates in k8s, and my DB migrations happen in an init container. I deploy my new application version that `DROP`s the policy and `CREATE`s the new one with the correct set of commands. Is there a window, however brief between `CREATE` and `DROP`, where the still running old pod now has access to everything? Intuition says "definitely", but testing a fraction of a second race condition is hard. Can I prevent this window by wrapping the `DROP`/`CREATE` in a transaction? Are there other methods to make this safe?

Real world, the correct answer is "your deployed version has a security vulnerability. Scale to 0 and deploy the correct version", but I'm trying to think through the vulnerabilities this set up brings, and others doing the deploy in the future may not be so careful.

My current setup is running 9.6, but there's a plan in the medium-term to work it up to 15.1, so answers for either version are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A row level security policy allows a role to do something, so dropping the policy will *reduce* what the user can do. If you are worried that this can cause errors or bad results for concurrent queries, wrap the `DROP POLICY` and CREATE POLICY` statements in a single transaction, then all concurrent queries get blocked. That shouldn't be a problem, because both statements are fast.

Comment: Right! I'm realizing I left out a bit. For backwards compatibility with existing services, there's a separate "allow all" policy and the policy being talked about here is a `RESTRICTIVE` added on top for the new application's user. Still, you answered the heart of my question, which was "does a transaction remedy this scenario?". Thank you!